# How to install oracleJDK8 through docker file in ubuntu

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I need to install oracle jdk8 through docker.

Currently I am doing the open jdk8 by 
    apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: I don't think there's a way to install Oracle JDK from the terminal. You have to manually download it and put it somewhere the Dockerfile can find it. Unless you specifically need Oracle JDK, I'd consider sticking to OpenJDK as it has nearly everything.

Comment: Yes.  Oracle insists that you agree to the license before downloading Oracle JDKs and JREs.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Dockerfile`, use next to download oracle JDK:

```
RUN curl -L -b "oraclelicense=a" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/${hash}/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz -O
```

Or

```
RUN curl -L -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/{hash}/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz -O
```

NOTE: you need to find different ${hash} for above url & also change versions.

After download, use `ln -s` to make symbol link for `java`, `jre` to `/bin`, then you make it.

BTW, I did not finish download the package as it's really time consume, after download, you need to extract it & make symbol link in `Dockerfile` for yourself.

Finally, per @StephenC 's suggestion, I do not paste full url as he suggested this may put the StackExchange organization at legal risk. You can goto [official site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html) to register an account to download the jdk you want. In the download url, you can see the ${hash}, replace the hash, then you can get the full worked link(Of course, to get it, you are required to accept License Agreement). Some material for your reference, [this](https://gist.github.com/hgomez/4697585) & [this](https://www.wikidsystems.com/support/faq/how-can-i-install-oracle-jdk-8-from-the-command-line/).

And, if you do not want to use above method, there is another solution:

Download the oracle jdk manually from oracle site, put it in a personal web server, in `Dockerfile`, download it from this personal server, this also could help you.

Comment: Yes, go to https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html, register a account to download we will see a hash in download url, replace it.

Comment: Yes, this is good to use file server to store predownload installer, I will update it later.

Comment: Remove full url according to @StephenC 's suggestion.

Comment: the problem is with using curl command , this file comes as jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz: HTML document text, ASCII text, with very long lines , and size is 8.0K however If I download directly from the oracle site, then its  gzip compressed data and size is 193MB...So I when I execute tar  xvzf , it fails

Comment: You have changed the hash in url?

Comment: Did you have proxy? The html should tell you what happened, also find a workable one from https://gist.github.com/hgomez/4697585

Comment: I tried without accessing my company network by enabling hotspot in mobile. Still the downloaded html tar.gz file says `We're sorry, the page you requested was not found` when I did `less jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz `

Comment: You tried this? `curl -L -b "oraclelicense=a" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz -O` , I'm now downloading, it's ok on my side...

Comment: yes working ok. I think there was slight difference in the initial curl command and the one you posted now.

Comment: Strange, you can have a compare. Anyway, this solution works for you now I think, you can complete your Dockerfile to see if it's ok later.